# Gauge colors using echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts4r

Based on the example I found [here](https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/42) I thought the code below would produce a gauge with three color ranges:

```
0 < x <= 1.5: green
1.5 < x <= 3: yellow
x > 3: red
```

Here's what I have:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(magrittr)

CA_gauge <- e_charts() %>% 
  e_gauge(4.1, 
          "INCIDENCE", 
          min=0, 
          max=20,
          axisLine = list(
            linestyle = list(
              color=list(
                c(1.5, "green"),
                c(3, "yellow"),
                c(20, "red")
              )
            ))) %>% 
  e_title("CA")

print(CA_gauge)
```

but what it produces is

[image]

I suspect I'm missing something basic...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two point that need to be adjusted. `linestyle` needs a upper S - `lineStyle` - and the breacks have to be percentages.

Futhermore you can add `splitNumber` to adjust the breaks and make te gauge more readable.

```
# breaks in percentage 
1.5 / 20 = 0.075
3 / 20 = 0.15 
20 / 20 = 1
```

```
CA_gauge <- e_charts() %>% 
  e_gauge(4.1, 
          "INCIDENCE", 
          min=0, 
          max=20,
          splitNumber = 20,
          axisLine = list(
            lineStyle = list(
              color=list(
                c(0.075, "green"),
                c(.15, "yellow"),
                c(1, "red")
              )
            ))) %>% 
  e_title("CA")

print(CA_gauge)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried changing them to percentages and got the same behavior....can't believe I missed the capital S!